# Does flutter have problem with exynos cpu/gpu?

Tags: flutter, dart, flare, exynos

I was writing a simple app which has a stack with a moving animation at the background and simple textfields at the front. On emulator in debug mode the app runs smoother than on my Galaxy J6. UI frames are 3-4ms but GPU thread shows 23-25 ms and 30-48fps on average.

I saw another thread about exynos cpu problem but I can't comment there because of some reputation stuff. I also checked the flare examples and run the penguin animation and it is worse than mine with responsive UI but GPU is working hard as hell.

An suggestions?

Here is my flutter doctor:

> ```
> [✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.9.1+hotfix.2, on Linux, locale en_US.UTF-8)
>     • Flutter version 1.9.1+hotfix.2 at /home/addaedans/FlutterSDK/flutter
>     • Framework revision 2d2a1ffec9 (3 weeks ago), 2019-09-06 18:39:49 -0700
>     • Engine revision b863200c37
>     • Dart version 2.5.0
>
> [✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.1)
>     • Android SDK at /home/addaedans/AndroidSDK
>     • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
>     • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.1
>     • ANDROID_HOME = /home/addaedans/AndroidSDK
>     • ANDROID_SDK_ROOT = /home/addaedans/AndroidSDK
>     • Java binary at: /opt/android-studio/jre/bin/java
>     • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b49-5587405)
>     • All Android licenses accepted.
>
> [✓] Android Studio (version 3.5)
>     • Android Studio at /opt/android-studio
>     • Flutter plugin version 39.0.3
>     • Dart plugin version 191.8423
>     • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b49-5587405)
>
> [✓] Connected device (2 available)
>     • SM J600FN • 5200bd8f5839a515 • android-arm • Android 9 (API 28)
>     • Android SDK built for x86 • emulator-5554 • android-x86 • Android 9 (API 28)
>       (emulator)
> ```